# Python2.7 __init__.py error - ValueError: Empty module name

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am new to Django python framework and as a beginner, I am going through the documentation of Django from the official website. But at [Part-2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial02/), When I run the makemigration command I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/shivams334/venv1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/shivams334/venv1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/shivams334/venv1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/shivams334/venv1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/shivams334/venv1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ValueError: Empty module name
```

I also tried to locate the /usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py file, here it is:

```
    """Backport of importlib.import_module from 3.x."""
# While not critical (and in no way guaranteed!), it would be nice to keep this
# code compatible with Python 2.3.
import sys

def _resolve_name(name, package, level):
    """Return the absolute name of the module to be imported."""
    if not hasattr(package, 'rindex'):
        raise ValueError("'package' not set to a string")
    dot = len(package)
    for x in xrange(level, 1, -1):
        try:
            dot = package.rindex('.', 0, dot)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("attempted relative import beyond top-level "
                          "package")
    return "%s.%s" % (package[:dot], name)


def import_module(name, package=None):
    """Import a module.

    The 'package' argument is required when performing a relative import. It
    specifies the package to use as the anchor point from which to resolve the
    relative import to an absolute import.

    """
    if name.startswith('.'):
        if not package:
            raise TypeError("relative imports require the 'package' argument")
        level = 0
        for character in name:
            if character != '.':
                break
            level += 1
        name = _resolve_name(name[level:], package, level)
    __import__(name)
    return sys.modules[name]
```

I am using virtualenv so I don't know why am I getting this error.

My INSTALLED_APP list in mysite/settings.py is:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib..schemastaticfiles',
]
```

I am stuck with my django tutorial due to this error, please help.

Comment: What is this `'django.contrib..schemastaticfiles',`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
'django.contrib..schemastaticfiles',
```

to this:

```
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```